# give animation to div when a button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

css Of that Div:-

```
.PostBox {
position: fixed;
height: 60%;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
bottom: 0;
border-radius: 10px;
border-top: 5px solid rgb(16, 150, 233);
padding: 20px;
display: inline-table;

animation: SlidUp 3s ease-out backwards;
}
```

Animaion Of Div

```
@keyframes SlidUp {
  from {
    visibility: hidden;
    bottom: -60%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I Want to give this Animation Whenever a button is clicked, That Button just turns the visibility of this div to visible or hidden.

in short, I want to give animation when ever a button click or given animation whenever visibility change

Comment: you can set animaton property to a class and add this when you click the button

Comment: can you give me some ref codes or questions from Stack Over Flow? I am new in web development

Comment: You can just search on google 'How to toggle class'. Do you use jquery or vanilla js or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pure CSS/HTML without JavaScript if that is suitable for your particular use case.

The trick is to use an input of type checkbox. It needs to be before the PostBox and a sibling of PostBox.

Here's a simple example:

```css
.PostBox {
  position: fixed;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top: 5px solid rgb(16, 150, 233);
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-table;
}

input:checked~.PostBox {
  animation: SlidUp 3s ease-out backwards;
}

@keyframes SlidUp {
  from {
    visibility: hidden;
    bottom: -60%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Click me </label><input type="checkbox">
<div class="PostBox">I am the div that is going to slide up</div>
```

Obviously you'll want to refine things a bit - for example do you want the div to be there from the start? But that's a different question.

Comment: but how can i do this with button

Comment: If you want to do it with an HTML button (Is there a reason for needing that) you will have to write some JavaScript. I gave the CSS-only version because you have mentioned only HTML and CSS in the tags. If you want a JS version then have a go at coding it and if still stuck put the JS and other structures into your question with a description of what isn't working.

Comment: any example of js with button

Comment: An afterthought - do you want a button simply so it looks like a button? If so you can style the label/input combo to look like a button. However, if you definitely need an HTML button then JS is required.

Comment: To find JS and have a go please do some searching - for click event and toggle function I would suggest to start with. SO doesn't like us to just code ab initio.